# Getting Data together for program and campaigns from three tables

Tags: oracle, responsys

I'm facing the following problem. 
I have a list of Back in Stock requests. Each request gets its own RIID and the email is hashed. I also have the product id of the product.

What I then created is a SQL view that pulls the contact data from the profile list (contact list) and the product data I need from a SUP feed. This SUP feed is not connected to the contact list via RIID or similar.

My problem then is how to get the data from all 3 lists into a mail for personalization. I can't access the data from the SQL View, can I? The Back in Stock list is not provided with email addresses and the product list is disproportionate to the contacts. Does anyone have an idea?

Here are examples:

```
BIS.List fields:
Email_Hash, RIID_, PRODUCTID

CONTACT.List fields:
Email, Email_Hash

Product_Feed fields:
PRODUCTID, PRODUCT_IMAGE

SQL View RESULT fields:
Email, RIID, PRODUCTID
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], edit your questions and show the table definitions, example data, expected output.

Answer (score 0):

In the Campaign Dashboard, open the Data Sources window. Add all the supplemental tables you need (remember to assign lookup fields and aliases to each table).

In your Campaign source, use the #data command (RPL) to fetch the fields and filter the results from each of the suplemental tables.

RPL Documentation: [RPL_Reference_Guide.pdf](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCEA/Resources/RPL_Reference_Guide.pdf)